# Which controller should handle the request when displaying all categories + all posts belonging to current category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have a `Post` model with a many-to-one association to a `Category` model.

In the view I'm working with I want to display all categories in the navigation and in the content area all posts belonging to currently selected category.

Should I route a request for this webpage through the "PostsController" or the "CategoriesController"? I know that both are *technically* possible.

Comment: I would say CategoriesController because you're filtering posts based on which category they're in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said

> I want to display all categories in the navigation and in the content
>   area all posts belonging to currently selected category

I think main page should fall in `CategoriesController`

But if if you are sending request after clicking specific category to load posts then this request should go to `PostsController`

**Reason:**
To follow the **[CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)** on page load it will load all `Categories` so it's index page of `Categories` so this should fall in `CategoriesController`

Same when you load all `post` related to that category then IMO that is more related to `PostsController`.

**EDIT:** As you said you are loading all data in one request then IMO you should use `CategoriesController`

Comment: What do you mean by ".. sending request after clicking .."? Don't all clicks result in a request?

Comment: As you said you are loading all data in one request then IMO you should use CategoriesController

Answer (score 0):

I would choose both: `CategoryController#index` list posts grouped by category, whereas `PostController#index` list posts by date and the category is just a small tag sign on each of them.

Comment: There's only one request, how and why would I need to route it through two controllers?

Comment: @MsNumbers : Just show two links categories and posts and let the user (or the search engine) decide which is more useful. I think the use case highly depends on what the user is looking for: information for a topic or just the most recent post.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `CategoriesController` because it's association is one-to-many posts. You will find it more convenient should your code becomes more complex in the future. Furthemore you could either use the `index` method of `Categories` (override it if you don't think that you would be having a page that will show just the list of categories as one full page), or you could create your own method. As for me, I would create a new method say `CategoriesController#posts_list`